# Simultaneously download from an FTP server different parts of the same file with multiple connection

Tags: java, scala, ftp, protocols

I want to download a very large file from an FTP server.
Is it possible to start downloading from a specific offset? 
My use cases are:
1. connection dropped during transfer, can I continue the download rather than start over?
2. can I use multiple connections with different offset to download the file faster using multiple connections simultaneously?

I'm working in scala, so ideally looking for JVM libs that offer this functionality. I couldn't find any tools offering this or even evidence for the FTP protocol supporting something like an offset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to start downloading from a specific offset?

Yes, if the FTP server supports it.<sup>1</sup>

> If connection dropped during transfer, can I continue the download rather than start over?

Yes, if the FTP server supports it.<sup>1</sup>

> Can I use multiple connections with different offset to download the file faster using multiple connections simultaneously?

Yes, if the FTP server supports it.<sup>1</sup>

> I'm looking for JVM libs that offer this functionality.

Please see [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) article "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)":

4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, *software library*, tutorial or other off-site resource are *off-topic* for Stack Overflow.

> I couldn't find evidence for the FTP protocol supporting something like an offset.

If you look at the full [list of FTP commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands), the `REST` command *(restart transfer from the specified point)* seems on point.

---

<sup>1) You can ask the FTP server what it supports using the `FEAT` command *(get the feature list implemented by the server)*.</sup>

Comment: the FTP server I work with does not support `FEAT`. lmao.

Comment: @polo: then just try to use the REST command. If the server responds with an error it is not supported.

Comment: @polo If it doesn't even support `FEAT`, then it's likely a very minimalistic FTP server that doesn't support `REST` either, in which case the answer is *no* to your questions. If you want start-at-offset support, you should upgrade the FTP server.